# RunTimeError in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am doing .net application which is in vb.I am getting an runtime error when running in Internet Explorer,but its running in mozilla. Error as following

> Error:SysArgumentTypeException:Object
>   of type
>   'AjaxControlToolKit.Animation.Length
>   Animation' cannot be converted to type
>   ;AjaxControlToolKit.Animation'.Parameter
>   Instance.

Error is getting in MicrosoftAjax.debug.js
if(!this.isInstanceOfType(instance)) throw Error.argumentType('instance',ObjectgetType(instance))

What may be the reason for this error.What can i do to resolve this? Can anybody help?

Comment: I don't know VB.net that much,but I can still fix your problem, you're going to have to put the code up here so i can see what are you trying to compare against

Comment: Sounds like a Javascript error.  You're probably getting it in Mozilla, too, but just not getting a popup.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates, that you are trying to cast a type called `Length Animation` to a type called `Parameter`. In VB and VB.NET, the cast is tried implicitly if the types of an assignment doesn't match. Please have a further look at the stack-trace to find the exact line of the error.

PS: I didn't know that there could be spaces in a .NET type name...